# How to build a self-sufficient gcc/glibc/binutils set in a non-standard path?

Tags: libraries, headers, gcc, glibc

Suppose a set of custom-built `gcc/glibc/binutils` are in `$prefix` (e.g. `/home/user/path`)

I want:

1. `gcc` to look for libraries in `$prefix/lib64` instead of `/lib64`
2. `gcc` to look for headers in `$prefix/include` instead of `/include`
3. to use `$prefix/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` as the (hard-coded) loader path instead of `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`
4. the dynamic loader to look for shared libraries in `$prefix/lib64` instead of `/lib64`

How should I configure the builds?  Do I need to modify `gcc`'s specs file or do anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [crosstool-ng](http://ymorin.is-a-geek.org/projects/crosstool). It is a very good script that builds toolchain with a Kconfig interface (like Linux kernel has). It allows you to configure almost everything in the toolchain, and it has the settings you need.

I once made an arm-gnueabi toolchain with it, and it works in any directory I unpacked the `.tbz2` to.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not support building cross-native (`build!=host==target`) tool-chain yet.

Comment: AFAIK there are no other similar utilities that support x86_64 (http://elinux.org/Toolchains#Toolchain_building_systems is a good overview). You can try just building the toolchain as usual, but set `--prefix $prefix` option for everything. (I think the toolchain building process is too complex to describe here, but `--prefix` trick has worked for me. Of course, it is much harder than using `crosstool-ng`, and you already need another cross-toolchain.)